# How do you create an octave toolbox?

Tags: java, octave

I have created my own java library but now I want to create my own octave toolbox.
How do I get started on this.
Is there a hello world tutorial on how to create a toolbox in octave?
Thanks

Comment: @Bohemian: thats what I am doing since then.. but with no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 2 main documents about it. The [official manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Packages.html) and the one for [Octave Forge](http://octave.sourceforge.net/developers.html) (they kind of overlap). Seems to me your code will be dependent on the java package. However, this package was merged into Octave core a few weeks ago and has been suffering a lot of changes there. You may want to test your package with the development sources.

Note however that octave packages that are simple wrapper around java libraries are likely to be frowned upon.